# using two different click animations in one nav bar

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide, nav

My website uses html with CSS file. My nav bar uses Jquery click animation. I want to add another level of animation to the nav functions, but can't figure out how to insert another click animation (slide/toggle) without disrupting the existing click animation (scrolling).

Here is how it is set up now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Jonah Rapino - Film Scoring</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rapino.css" media="screen, projection"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=OFL+Sorts+Mill+Goudy+TT' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="" type="image/x-icon">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
$("#nav").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var theClicked = $(e.target).attr("href"),
  targetImg = $(theClicked).offset().top;
  $("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop : targetImg -10,
  }, 1400);
//console.log(targetImg)
});
});
</script>
</body>

<div id="content"> 
<div id="nav"> 
<ul class="listless">
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#current-work">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="#feature-film-scores">Film</a></li>
  <li><a href="#silent-film-scores">Silent</a></li>
  <li><a href="#classical-music">Classical</a></li>
  <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
  <li><a href="#friends">Friends</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I want:
I want to insert a toggle function to the Work link. When you click Work a pop down sub menu containing the links - Film, Silent, Classical appear and you can click on them and the page scrolls to the target indicated. Currently they are just static links.

I hope my language/layout isn't confusing or a waste of time here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
$('#nav a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if($(this).attr('href') === '#current-work') {
      // do your animation for work
   }
   else {
      // do animation for all other items
      var targetImg = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
      $("html,body").animate({
         scrollTop : targetImg -10,
      }, 1400);
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks so much for the feedback. I am unsure where to put this code you offered. Do I replace the existing jquery code with what you've provided, or do I add it to what is already there. Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: @user1483272 it's not complete code but you would take parts of the code you have and merge it with mine. I honestly think you need to learn more js/jquery before doing anymore or you will run into all kinds of problems unless someone can walk you through stuff step by step

Comment: cool, i don't know enough about using js/jquery. I was hoping for a quick fix. Thanks

Comment: well basically what you have in your code is the animation for all others, so if you know enough to figure out how to write the animation for work then it is fixed